# JFrame minimize icon query?

Tags: java, icons

I was able to hide the the maximize icon by setting `setResizable(false)`, how can achieve the same for the minimize icon?

Comment: Yet another programmer on the way to making an unusable (difficult, awkward, counter-intuitive) GUI.  :(  The best advice I can offer is **don't do that!**

Comment: Sometimes a program may be deployed on a device in full screen mode, for example ATM user interface.

Answer (score 2):

Here is the way, how to remove min/max buttons from JFrame

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class JFrameTest extends JDialog {
    public JFrameTest(JFrame frame, String str) {
        super(frame, str);
        addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
            public void windowClosing(WindowEvent evt) {
                System.exit(0);
            }
        });
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrameTest frame = new JFrameTest(new JFrame(), "Title");
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        panel.setSize(200, 200);
        JLabel lbl = new JLabel("JFrame without max/min");
        panel.add(lbl);
        frame.add(panel);
        frame.setSize(400, 400);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

*But it's really nasty to users and could be walk arounded by key shortcuts etc.*

Comment: Thank You,it will kind of u to explain me, what the major difference in the code and just declaring a JDialog?....

Comment: Almost none at all, you just can add some additional methods (logic) to your 'frame' if you want, 'cause it extends `JDialog`. Maybe one think, `JDialog` will not close you app if you'll click on close button (of course, you can add this behavior same way, but you would add this to all instances manually, now you have it in a class).

Answer (score 1):

Check the example [Specifying Window Decorations](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0240__Swing/SpecifyingWindowDecorations.htm)